# Trouble with Google chrome context menus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm having trouble with the Chrome API. Specifically, I can't seem to pass anything from my context menu onclick function.

```
var linkSafetyChild = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title":"Is this link safe?","parentId":linkParent,"contexts":[contexts[2]],"onclick":checkScamAdvisorLink});
```

which calls the function:

```
function checkScamAdvisorLink(info, tab){ alert(info.mediaType); var searchString = "h ttp://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/"; alert(info.linkURL); var siteToCheck = convertURLToSearchableString(info.linkURL); var finalString = searchString.concat(siteToCheck); }
```

but when I try to access the info object with `alert(info.mediaType)` and `alert(info.linkURL)` both return `undefined`. How can I pass this information to `checkScamAdvisorLink`?

The above excerpts are from `launch.js` specified in the manifest.

Manifest.json:

```
{ "manifest_version": 2, "name":"Hi-Brite Informational Assistant", "description": "This extension provides extended information and performs various helpful actions based on highlighted text. Just kidding, it does nothing", "version": "0.0.0", "browser_action": { "default_icon": "icon.png", "default_popup":"my_popup.html" }, "permissions": ["activeTab", "ht tps://ajax.googleapis.com/", "contextMenus","tabs"], "background":{ "scripts":["launch.js"] }, "content_scripts":[{ "matches": ["ht tps://www.tineye.com/"], "js":["TinyEyeSearch.js"] }]}
```

Comment: Hi please edit your question and use the "code" button to set your code

Comment: Sorry. It didn't give an option for that in mobile. Fixed now.

Comment: Hi,

According to google API:

> A function that will be called back when the menu item is clicked.
> Event pages cannot use this; instead, they should **register a listener**
> for chrome.contextMenus.onClicked. try register as event listener and not directly in onclicked

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I nearly typed out  long response about how it wasn't working and what I though it could be, but then I realized I had just miscapitalized linkUrl. Thanks a lot.